# Unable to read the buffer from BytesIO in google app engine flex environment

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

Here is the related code

```
import logging


logging.getLogger('googleapicliet.discovery_cache').setLevel(logging.ERROR)

import datetime
import json


from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask import make_response

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload

from oauth2client.client import AccessTokenCredentials

...

@app.route('/callback_download')
def userselectioncallback_with_drive_api():
    """
    Need to make it a background process
    """
    logging.info("In download callback...")

    code = request.args.get('code')

    fileId = request.args.get('fileId')
    logging.info("code %s", code)
    logging.info("fileId %s", fileId)

    credentials = AccessTokenCredentials(
        code,
        'flex-env/1.0')

    http = httplib2.Http()
    http_auth = credentials.authorize(http)

    # Exports a Google Doc to the requested MIME type and returns the exported content. Please note that the exported content is limited to 10MB.
    # v3 does not work? over quota?
    drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', http=http_auth)

    drive_request = drive_service.files().export(
        fileId=fileId,
        mimeType='application/pdf')

    b = bytes()
    fh = io.BytesIO(b)
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, drive_request)
    done = False

    try:
        while done is False:
            status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
            logging.log("Download %d%%.", int(status.progress() * 100))
    except Exception as err:
        logging.error(err)
        logging.error(err.__class__)

    response = make_response(fh.getbuffer())
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = \
            'inline; filename=%s.pdf' % 'yourfilename'

    return response
```

It is based on some code example of drive api. I am trying to export some files from google drive to pdf format.

The exception comes from the line

```
   response = make_response(fh.getbuffer())
```

It throws the exception:

```
TypeError: 'memoryview' object is not callable
```

How can I retrieve the pdf content properly from the `fh`?  Do I need to further apply some base 64 encoding?

My local runtime is python 3.4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used an incorrect API. I should do this instead:

```
response = make_response(fh.getvalue())
```